# Подпись для приватных методов

Tags: python, api

Нужно сформировать подпись. Никогда этого раньше не делал.
Вот как трактует это разработчики.

Ссылка на сериализацию
https://docs.kuna.io/docs/api-data-schema-and-serialization

```
HEX (
    HMAC-SHA384(
      {apiPath} + {nonce} + JSON({body}),
      {secretKey}
    )
)
```

Что у меня получилось.

```
 = 'https://api.kuna.io/v3/timestamp'

kun_signature = hex(hashlib.sha384(str(r) + str(1613639519) + str({})),{secret_key})
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1', 
'accept': 'application/json',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'kun-nonce': '1613639519',
'kun-apikey': public_key,
'kun-signature': kun_signature}

pool = requests.get(r, headers=headers)
print(pool)
```

Вывод

```
kun_signature = hex(hashlib.sha384(str(r) + str(1613639519) + str({})),{secret_key})
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Укажите, пожалуйста, на ошибки.

Comment: А куда вставлять `{secret_key})`?

Comment: Че то я погряз в терминах, а результат даже близко не стоит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
```

где:

- key - секретный ключ API ,
- msg - path + publikkey + timestamp

`timestamp` должен быть идентичный тому, который в `headers`

Comment: Подскажите, что подразумевается разрабами в timestamp? Метка времени запроса. Указывается в формате Unix Time Stamp в милисекундах (ms). Только для приватных методов.  Точкой отсчета что служит?

Comment: точкой отсчета служит точка отправки запроса , не нужно брать серверное время а получить его через time